# timestamp Spec in druid

Tags: druid

My data has timestamp like `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. I am using below spec for indexing:

```
 "timestampSpec" : {
            "format" : "mm/dd/yyyy",
            "column" : "createddate"
          }
```

Its giving the error `Caused by: com.metamx.common.parsers.ParseException: Unparseable timestamp found!`.

How can we handle this kind of data?

Comment: how about `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: I tried "M/dd/y H:m:s" and its working fine for me I will try your solution too. Thank you

Comment: Did it work? I have a pattern like 20180622143227 (like yyyyMMddHHmmss) i get success when i try to batch load , but no datasource is available...

Answer (score 2):

Druid timestamp spec can be iso, millis, posix, auto or any Joda time format. Here's the link to Joda time [pattern/style](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Reference - http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the below :
"timestampSpec" : {
            "format" : "iso",
            "column" : "createddate"
          }

or

"timestampSpec" : {
            "format" : "auto",
            "column" : "createddate"
          }